# How to configure custom url on Google Oauth2

Tags: react-native, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, custom-url

I'm trying to set up login with google on my react native app.

I set up my custom uri on Android as such:

```
    <intent-filter android:label="filter_react_native">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="com.myapp" android:host='app'/>
    </intent-filter>
```

And if I launch the app using com.myapp://app, everything works perfectly.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2InstalledApp#creatingcred

According to these docs, the redirect_uri can be a custom one. "Note that the path should begin with a single slash, which is different from regular HTTP URLs." The only way the redirect works without issue is this:

```
Linking.openURL([
  'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
  '?response_type=code',
  '&client_id=' + clientID,
  '&redirect_uri=com.myapp:/app',
  '&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login',
  '+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
  '+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
].join(''))
```

Except when I type my password and accept the terms, I get the following error:

```
The webpage at com.myapp:/app?code=XXXX could not be loaded because:
net:: ERROR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME
```

Where am I going wrong?